# Using OLEDB to return cursor from a plsql function to my C# Program

Tags: c#, plsql, cursor

I want to execute a SQL function that returns a cursor in my C# code. I am using OLEDB and it seems like OLEDB does not have the Cursor definition in the OleDbType. The cursor definition exists in OracleType, but since I am using OLEDB I don't want to change all my code.

```
OleDbCommand cmMyCommand = new OleDbCommand();

cmMyCommand.CommandText = "LUXF_EDI_SIG_DATA_SELECT_AS";

cmMyCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmMyCommand.Parameters.Add("p_grgr_id", OleDbType.VarChar);
cmMyCommand.Parameters["p_grgr_id"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
cmMyCommand.Parameters["p_grgr_id"].Value = grgrid;


cmMyCommand.Parameters.Add("p_return_cursor", OleDbType.Cursor);--This is not working.
cmMyCommand.Parameters["p_return_cursor"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmMyCommand.Parameters["p_return_cursor"].Value = null;
```

Comment: maybe this can help you - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/win.920/a95498/using.htm

Comment: I am actually curios as to what your stored procedure looks like..  do you have the `p_return_cursor` defined in the actual stored procedure..? in  your stored procedure before you do the SELECT statement make sure you have this `OPEN p_return_cursor FOR`

Comment: Here is the PL/SQL Block, That needs to be executed                   DECLARE
  PGRGR_ID VARCHAR2(200);
  PRESULT_CURSOR CURSOR_PACKAGE.RESULT_CURSOR;
  v_Return NUMBER;
BEGIN
  PGRGR_ID := NULL;

  V_RETURN := LUXF_EDI_SIG_DATA_SELECT_AS(
    PGRGR_ID => 'xxxxx',
    PRESULT_CURSOR => PRESULT_CURSOR
  );
  /* Legacy output: 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_Return = ' || v_Return);
*/ 
  :v_Return := v_Return;
  /* Legacy output: 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRESULT_CURSOR = ' || PRESULT_CURSOR);
*/ 
  :PRESULT_CURSOR := PRESULT_CURSOR; --<-- Cursor
END;